# Display contents of an Azure storage container via web browser

Tags: azure-storage

first post at stack so be nice :)

I've created an Azure storage account with a container in it. I've set the container access policy to 'Container'.

I have added a file to that storage container and can browse to that. However when I browse to the actual container path I get a 404.

I was expecting that I'd be able to get a file list type view on the container when I set the container access policy. Am I missing something? Is there any way to display a folder list type view on an Azure storage container?

The container that gives the 404 is :
https://maxonazurecoolstorage.blob.core.windows.net/stuff

The file is located here and opens ok
https://maxonazurecoolstorage.blob.core.windows.net/stuff/Field-1_jpg.jpg

any help greatly appreciated

cheers

Max

Answer (score 14):

According to your description, you have set Access type to Container, and you’d like to list Blobs from your container, you could refer to the following [List Blobs request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/list-blobs) to enumerate the list of blobs under the specified container.

> > https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer?restype=container&comp=list

Comment: that's great, thanks.. this provides me an XML style listing, is there any way at present to get a virtual directory style listing, with hyperlinked files?

Comment: You could retrieve and output the URI of each item in the specified container by using the container's [ListBlobs method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs#list-the-blobs-in-a-container).

Comment: Hey @maxwellsmartish, you should probably mark this answer as the correct answer.

Comment: It doesn't look like there's a nicer way provided according to the API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs

Comment: I also wanted to do something like using the browser to access the container but show the listing of the container.  Instead of what @FeiHan posted, I was hoping to just access ```https://<bloburl>/container``` and it shows the listing.  At this moment, I don't think this works even though the public access is set to Container.

Comment: Perhaps a static html file in the blob that calls this list method and transforms the results into links? This could be a standard addition to blobs for public consumption.